# How can I find (and scrape) all web pages on a given domain using Python?

Tags: python, http, dns

How would I scrape a domain to find all web pages and content?

For example: www.example.com, www.example.com/index.html, www.example.com/about/index.html and so on..

I would like to do this in Python and preferable with Beautiful Soup if possible..

Comment: This would probably fit better on StackOverflow... But what you are describing is a web-crawler. Try Googling that.

Comment: Depending on your needs and what the specific website allows, scraping may not be your best alternative. Many free content projects provide database dumps for their content, for example [Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-are-the-stack-exchange-data-dumps) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download). Other domains provide APIs for accessing their content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Pages not only can pages be dynamically generated based on backend database data and search queries or other input that your program supplies to the website, but there is a nearly infinite list of possible pages, and the only way to know which ones exist is to test and see.

The closest you can get is to scrape a website based on hyperlinks between pages in the page content itself.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed this was the case!

Comment: I don't think this is true. There are info security tools that "spider," go and follow all the links from one page to all the others (as long as they're still in the domain), and rinse and repeat.

OP, you could build such code yourself using BeautifulSoup, using Python to go to all the links on that page that are in the same domain, and do the same on each of those pages.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python library [newspaper](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper)

Install using `sudo pip3 install newspaper3k`

You can scrape all the articles on a particular website.

```
from newspaper import Article
url = "http://www.example.com"
built_page = newspaper.build( url )
print("%d articles in %s\n\n"%(built_page.size(), url))
for article in built_page.articles:
    print(article.url)
```

From there you can use the [Article object API](http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/quickstart.html#news-articles) to get all sorts of information from the page including the raw HTML.